# Selenium test fail

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I close the browser in selenium using the method as `driver.quit()` it showing error message in eclipse. I used if condition as

it closed the browser but showing error as in eclipse. Please help

```
if(i>=4) { driver.quit(); }
```

Comment: what error is it showing?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'admin-pc', ip: '192.168.8.5', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)

Comment: Debug your code. The browser might have been closed before it reached this code.

Comment: @ vivek Singh, Not that issue

Comment: then  put wait before you quit/close driver.

Comment: showing like this Jan 30, 2015 2:56:35 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:7056: Connection reset
Jan 30, 2015 2:56:35 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:7056

Comment: please share your whole code in question.

Comment: we would like to see what are you trying before closing the browser which is causing this problem? also can you tell us what browser, version and webdriver version are u using

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, i hope it will helps you(sometimes it helps me) :

```
  try{if(i>=4) {driver.quit();}catch(Exception e ){}}
```